# Why can't I name a folder in a project 'texmf/fonts' etc., even though it says you can in the manual?

Tags: fonts, overleaf

I'm trying to install a commerical font (mtpro2) into a project on Overleaf and I need to create folders in the project which contain specific files related to the font. I'm following the Overleaf manual article:

https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/I_have_a_custom_font_I%27d_like_to_load_to_my_document._How_can_I_do_this%3F#If_you.27re_using_pdfLaTeX_or_LaTeX

It says I need to create folders called 'texmf/', 'texmf/fonts/type1/', etc., but Overleaf won't let me use the '/' character in the name of a folder.
How am I supposed to get round this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `/` is the char for separating folders. Thus first create `texmf`, as a subfolder to that create `fonts` etc until you have created all the needed folders and subfulders. Overleaf will probably not let you create `texmf` and the `fonts` subfolder in one go. And Overleaf runs on linix and there `/` is not allowed in the name of a folder.

Comment: Ah - thank you so much!

Comment: note that when installing on a system for use in multiple documents it is better to lay out the expected directory tree but an overleaf project is a single doument use so it would also work and be simpler to just put all the files in the main top level directory

Comment: Yeah - okay, thanks for your tip!

Comment: I'm still having some trouble, I think it might be to do with which files I am putting in which folders (I also tried your suggestion David, but it also didn't work). I don't see any mtpro2 files that could go into 'texmf/fonts/afm' or '.../vf' or '.../enc'. Any ideas?